# android sample SQLcipher not working in device

Tags: android, database, sqlcipher

I use a sample of SQLcipher android database it works in the AVD emulator but not in my Sony Xperia device.

Comment: provide related code, and exception stacktrace

Comment: i-c"an t understood ?????????????

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include your code along with a better explanation of what "not working in device" means.